# Compare database date with user input

Tags: python, web2py

In drop down, I have some values like Due today , Due Tomorrow , This Year, This Month. When user will select any option from the drop down. I want to fetch the data from the  table according to the option. if I will select due today, Only today date record should be shown. if i select this month,Only monthly record should be shown  I am not able to under stand how i can convert the string into date. and compare with database. 
def abc():
Model

```
db.define_table('Birthday',
   Field('Name',label='name'),
   Field('assignment','text'),
   Field('bdate','date')
```

View

```
function showcnf()
{
var x=document.forms["cnf"]["sub"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please select the value ");
  return false;
  }

</script> 


<form name="cnf" action="{{=URL('default','subquery')}}" method="post" onsubmit="return showcnf()" >
<select name="sub">
  <option value="Due Today">Due Today</option>
  <option value="Due Tommarow">Due Tomorrow</option>
  <option value="Due This Month">Due This Month</option>
     <option value="Due This Month">Due This Month</option>


</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{{=grid}}
```

In controller I have used 2 function. First for taking the input and second one i am trying to compare . but i am not able to do. i have not any idea for doing that. 
i have gone throw the following link

http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html

i have not found some thing for me .

Controller

```
def abc():

    subject=request.vars.sub
    if subject == 'Due Today':
        redirect(URL(r=request,f='jmd' ))

    if subject == 'Due Tommarow':
        redirect(URL(c='default',f='jmd'))
    if subject == 'Due This Month':
        redirect(URL(c='default',f='jmd'))


    response.flash = T("its working !")

    return dict()




def jmd():
    table=SQLFORM.grid(db.Birthday,create=False,deletable=False,editable=False,csv=False)
    response.flash = T("done")
    return dict(grid=table)
```

can any one can help me  in this 
Thanks
Rohit Raj Sharma

Answer (score 0):

you don't need two functions

```
def abc():

subject=request.vars.sub
if subject == 'Due Today':
    queries = (db.Birthday==datetime.date.today())

if subject == 'Due Tommarow':
    queries = ...
if subject == 'Due This Month':
    queries = ...


response.flash = T("its working !")
table=SQLFORM.grid(queries,create=False,deletable=False,editable=False,csv=False)

return dict()
```